# Очистка буфера ввода cin

Tags: c++, input

Привет. Есть код.

```
char friend_sex = 0;

//check if sex is valid
bool ok_sex = false;
//---------------------

while (!ok_sex){

    cout << "Enter the sex of your mutual friend\n";

    // What is sex of that person?
    cout << "M or W: \n";
    //----------------------------

    cin >> friend_sex;

    if(friend_sex == 'M' || friend_sex == 'W'){

        ok_sex = true;

    }

}
```

Я только учу С++ и хочу сделать обработку неправильного введения пола друга.
К примеру, пользователь вводит что-то кроме `W` и `M` и запрос на введение повторяется в цикле, что видно из кода. Также будет происходить, если пользователь введет много символов вместо одного. Но тут есть один момент. Дело в том, что так как тип переменной `friend_sex` char, то из потока ввода последовательность символов считывается посимвольно. Я написал `abcd`, допустим, но считалось сначала `a`, потом (если это в цикле, берется второй символ и происходит проверка, и так до конца). По сути, если написать `abcMf`, то на проверке четвертого символа цикл завершится, ибо проверка будет пройдена.

**Вопрос:** Я хочу, чтобы при введение последовательности символов, считывался первый, а буфер ввода очищался от оставшихся. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, функцию очистки буфера (cin.clear() не работает).

Comment: `cin.flush()` пробовали?

Comment: @pavel компилятор выдает ошибку, грит нет такого метода в std::istream

Comment: @Muller: А не забыли ли вы `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: тогда `flushall();` только не помню в какой он библиотеке

Comment: @VladD нет, конечно, а то бы не мог бы ни вводить, ни выводить.

Comment: *Булы и так, сами по себе инициализируються в false.

Comment: Извините, а как Ваше сообщение отвечает на вопрос?

Comment: @ВениаминВеличко - вы категорически неправы, bool ни во что не инициализируется, чтение из неинициализированной переменной есть UB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
cin.clear(); // на случай, если предыдущий ввод завершился с ошибкой
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Не забудьте

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло.

Comment: @Muller: `cin.clear()` очищает признак ошибки, если он у `cin` взвёлся (с признаком ошибки дальнейший ввод не пройдёт). `cin.ignore(...)` пропускает во входном потоке всё до следующего `\n` (то есть, до конца строки).

Comment: @Muller: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Проще считывать всю строку:

```
std::string friend_sex;
do {
  std::cout << "Enter the sex of your mutual friend\nM or W: \n";
  if (!getline(std::cin, friend_sex))
    return;  // поток ввода закрылся
} while (friend_sex != "M" && friend_sex != "W");
```

Comment: Я тоже так думал. Но теперь попробуйте ввести два слова и вам выдаст запрос на ввод пола два раза, а если введете три слова, то три, ибо строка считывается через пробельные разделители. То есть почти тоже самое, что и посимвольно.

Comment: Да, это тоже вариант, вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

Можно также с помощью директивы #define создать макрос и затем им пользоваться. Например,

```
#define CIN_FLUSH if (std::cin.peek()) std::cin.ignore()
```

Answer (score 0):

используй этот код очистки cin перед самим cin:

```
if(char(cin.peek()) == '\n')
    cin.ignore();

if (cin.fail()) 
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
}
```